# Android - Expandable ListView how to animate group indicator without affect others

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a problem to animate a group indicator. It animates all other group indicators in different positions. I tried to discriminate it by tag with no effect. What I want is animate only the group I clicked.

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ... 
     if(isExpanded){
        ObjectAnimator animator =   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(containerIndicator,"rotation",0,180f);
        animator.setDuration(400);
        animator.start();
        //arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_accordion_open);
        headerTitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.euronics_blue));



    }else{
        if(arrowImage.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(getGroup(groupPosition).name)) {
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(containerIndicator, "rotation", 180f,0);
            animator.setDuration(400);
            animator.start();
        }
     ...
```

}

Comment: I think the problem is with the view(containerIndicator) that you are passing to "ObjectAnimator.ofFloat".

Comment: @ArsalanShah can u post an example of how to fix it? thanks

Comment: @AugustoPicciani Did you solved your issue? I wanted to know how to fix it.?

Comment: @suman no sorry I didn't fix it. I completely changed my layout

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConsumptionExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<ConsumptionItem> data;

    private SparseBooleanArray expandState = new SparseBooleanArray();

    public ConsumptionExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<ConsumptionItem> data) {
        mContext = context;
        this.data = data;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            expandState.append(i, false);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderGroup {
        private HashMap<Integer, View> storedViews = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

        public ViewHolderGroup() { }

        public ViewHolderGroup addView(View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            storedViews.put(id, view);
            return this;
        }

        public View getView(int id) {
            return storedViews.get(id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ConsumptionItem consumptionItem = data.get(groupPosition);

        View view = v;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_consumption_group, viewGroup, false);
            final TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            final TextView serial = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.serial);
            final ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            final ImageView arrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.arrow);

            ViewHolderGroup holder = new ViewHolderGroup();

            holder.addView(name);
            holder.addView(serial);
            holder.addView(icon);
            holder.addView(arrow);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolderGroup holder = (ViewHolderGroup) view.getTag();

        final TextView name = (TextView) holder.getView(R.id.name);
        final TextView serial = (TextView) holder.getView(R.id.serial);
        final ImageView icon = (ImageView) holder.getView(R.id.icon);
        final ImageView arrow = (ImageView) holder.getView(R.id.arrow);

        name.setText(consumptionItem.getName());
        serial.setText(consumptionItem.getSerial());
        arrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp);

        if(consumptionItem.isStatus())
            icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_ok_green);
        else
            icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_ok_red);

        if (isExpanded && !expandState.get(groupPosition)) {
            animateExpand(arrow);
            expandState.put(groupPosition, true);
        }
        else if(!isExpanded && expandState.get(groupPosition)) {
            animateCollapse(arrow);
            expandState.put(groupPosition, false);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void animateExpand(View v) {
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0, 90);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.start();
    }

    private void animateCollapse(View v) {
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 90, 0);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.start();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ConsumptionItem consumptionItem = data.get(groupPosition);
        final ConsumptionItem.Item item = consumptionItem.getItems().get(childPosition);
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_consumption_child, viewGroup, false);

        final TextView month = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.month);
        final TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        final TextView indications = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.indications);

        month.setText(item.getMonth());
        date.setText(DateManager.getDateManager().getDateString(item.getDate()));
        indications.setText(String.valueOf(item.getReadings()));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return data.get(groupPosition).getItems().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return data.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return data.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add more information about what you have made because your anser is code only.